# Как добавить дерево данных в БД используя EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

у меня еcть DTO

```
public record CategoryDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

    public string Url { get; set; } = null!;
    
    public int Parent { get; set; }

    public IReadOnlyList<CategoryDto> Childs { get; set; } = Array.Empty<CategoryDto>();
}
```

Есть сущность

```
[Table("t_category")]
public class Category : BaseEntity,
    IHasUniqueName
{
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

    [MaxLength(255)] 
    public string Url { get; set; } = null!;
    
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    
    public Category? Parent { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; } = Array.Empty<Category>();
}
```

DTO я получаю со стороннего сайта м не нужно эту DTO преобразовать в сущность и добавить в базу. Как это сделать? Как используя средства EF Core добавлять такие данные?

Сервис который я набросал, тут думаю сформировать сущность и вызвав метод Insert у репозитория просто добавть данные

```
public class CategoryService : ICategoryService
{
    private readonly ICategoryRepository _categoryRepository;
    private readonly ICategoryParser _categoryParser;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public CategoryService(ICategoryRepository categoryRepository,
        ICategoryParser categoryParser,
        IMapper mapper)
    {
        _categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
        _categoryParser = categoryParser;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public async Task InitAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var dtos = await _categoryParser.GetAllAsync(cancellationToken);

        foreach (var dto in dtos)
        {
            var category = _mapper.Map<Category>(dto);
            await _categoryRepository.InsertAsync(category, cancellationToken);

            if (dto.Childs.Any())
                //await AddChildrenAsync(category.Id, dto.Childs);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `InsertAsync` - я так понимаю, это ваша обертка над простыми `db.Categories.Add(...)` и `db.SaveChanges()`? Если да, то `SaveChanges()` стоит вызывать только после добавления всех сущностей, а не каждую итерацию. Что касается добавления "Детей", то перед добавлением ищите в базе наличие данной категории (по ID), если есть - добавляйте ей все новые данные (или обновляйте старые), ну а если нету, то создавайте новую категорию и ей уже все это добавляйте.

Comment: Если у DTO нет свойства `Id`, то и свойство `Parent` вроде как не имеет смысла?